# How to count how many data points there are for a scattergraph?

Tags: r, sum, scatter-plot

```
Plot_Carnivore <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = dat1_carnivore, 
               aes(x = AdultBodyMass_g, 
                   y = Range_Area_km2)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = lm) +
    scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = scales::comma) +   
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = scales::comma) +
    ggtitle("Adult Body Size vs Geographic Range Size Of Carnivora") +
      labs(x = "Adult Body Size In Grams", y = "Range Size In Km^2")
```

How do I count how many data points I have in my scattergraph as I had some datapoints removed due to some not containing any value from my data set so it cannot plot it. Please help.

Comment: `nrow(dat1_carnivore) - sum(is.na(log10(dat1_carnivore$AdultBodyMass_g)) | is.na(log10(dat1_carnivore$Range_Area_km2)))` should give the number of non-NA points plotted.

Comment: another way: `sum(is.na(layer_data(Plot_Carnivore)$x) | is.na(layer_data(Plot_Carnivore)$y))`